# const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();

Tags: ethers.js

```
const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
```

When I am trying to deploy the contract I am getting a error at the above line and error is

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit
```

I am using ethers version ^5.7.2